# Postgres jsonb: querying multi level

Tags: postgresql

In a Postgres (9+) table there is a column of type `jsonb` with the following `json`:

```
{
   "dynamicFields":[
      {
         "name":"040",
         "subfields":[
            {
               "name":"a",
               "value":"abc"
            },
            {
               "name":"a",
               "value":"xyz"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to write a query that return only the rows where the field name equals `040` and subfield `a` equals `xyz`.

This is as far as I got, so far:

```
select e.obj from my_table
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(my_column-> 'dynamicFields') as e(obj)
where e.obj ->> 'name' = '040' and e.obj ->> 'subfields' @> '{"name": "a", "value": "xyz"}'::jsonb
```

How should this query be to achieve this?

Comment: "9+" covers 13 different major versions 5 from them no longer being supported (and 3 of them do not even have `jsonb`) . Which version are you _really_ using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.obj ->> 'subfields'` has a `text` result. You'll want to use `e.obj -> 'subfields'` that returns the `jsonb` value where the `@>` operator works. Also the containment checks needs to have another array as the right hand side, so that it will test whether all values in the right array are contained in the left array - it doesn't work to pass the element object directly.

```
select e.obj from my_table
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(my_column-> 'dynamicFields') as e(obj)
where e.obj ->> 'name' = '040' and e.obj -> 'subfields' @> '[{"name": "a", "value": "xyz"}]'::jsonb
--                                        ^                 ^                             ^
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fe04de508b8344091e9375616a8abf9a))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As you have an equality condition you can use the "contains" operator directly by providing a JSON value of what you want. There is no need to unnest the arrays.

```
select *
from my_table
where my_column -> 'dynamicFields' @> '[{"name": "040", "subfields": [{"name":"a", "value": "xyz"}]}]'
```

Starting with Postgres 12 an alternative is to a SQL/JSON path operator:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_column @? '$.dynamicFields[*] ? (@.name == "040").subfields[*] ? (@.name == "a" && @.value == "xyz")'
```